# Android - Executing a function after onBackPressed();

Tags: android

I have an Activity with a toolbar item that executed the following code:

```
case android.R.id.home:
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
```

the `onBackPressed();` returns the user to my MainActivity.

My question: How I can execute a function in my MainActivity activity after accessing it with the `onBackPressed();` method? Is that even possible?

Comment: you should use `startActivityForResult`

Comment: I need my inputs in my MainAcitvity to stay same as pressed the `back` button

Comment: the two things are unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your MainActivity you have to start the new Activity using **startActivityForResult**
like this:

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, yourRequestCode);
```

**yourRequestCode** is a int you can use to get the result from the **NewActivity**

In **NewActivity** you can override the **onBackPressed()** method:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  /* no call super() */
  setResult(RESULT_OK);
  finish();
}
```

So on your **MainActivity** you can get this result with **onActivityResult** and run your method:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == yourRequestCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        // here you can call your method !
    }

}
```